# Passing data between segue with Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, swift2, segue

I seem to be following tutorials to the tee yet I can't get my data to pass to my second view controller without being nil. 
I am new to Swift so I'm probably also not using optionals correctly. Here is how I have my code set up.

```
import UIKit

class DetailsViewController: UIViewController {

    var book : PLBook?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //View Did Load
        print(self.book)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    }
}
```

Then this is how I am presenting the second view controller and preparing for segue.

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toDetailVC", sender:self)
    }

    //MARK: Navigation

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "toDetailVC"){
            //prepare for segue to the details view controller

            if let detailsVC = sender?.destinationViewController as? DetailsViewController {
                let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
                detailsVC.book = self.books[indexPath!.row]
            }

        }
    }
```

In the second view controller, the book var is always nil. Any ideas how I can get the data to pass?

Comment: how certain are you that `detailsVC.book` is not nil?

Comment: print(self.book) logs nil

Comment: ye but print `detailsVC.book` after you assign it in the segue to make sure you arent actually passing it nil, if it is nil, then you have a problem with your self.books array rather than passing your data over a segue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `segue.destinationViewController`, not `sender?.destinationViewController`.

Answer (score 3):

Try This:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender:    AnyObject?)   {

if (segue.identifier == "toDetailVC") {

 //prepare for segue to the details view controller

           let detailsVC = segue.destinationViewController as!  DetailsViewController

            let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
            detailsVC.book = self.books[indexPath!.row]

}
```